# Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid language tag

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I'm seeing the following error with arcgis js api

```
Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid language tag
```

I've posted in the GIS community, but opening up to broader SO audience.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356538/uncaught-in-promise-rangeerror-invalid-language-tag

**NB** The same error is visible on the official arcgis website (see screenshots in post).

Issue seems to be with arcgis' use of dojo.js library. I'm not seeing docs on how to set dojo config in context of arcgis (without custom build).

Anyone got pointers on setting dojo config?

Comment: The arcgis api website works fine for me. Looking at the message it seems it is a problem with the language tag, I even try using en-AU and it works. Try changing the language of chrome to English US and refresh page.

Comment: @cabesuon I agree that the problem is the language tag. In fact, if I use a different computer, it works for me too. BUT that is the problem. My endusers should not not have to "use a different computer" or "change the language of chrome". Imagine if that were how Google maps worked. I think the arcgis js api should "be smarter" and at least have a fallback. More importantly, the arcgis api should have a way for me the dev to configure the underlying dojo js library to eliminate this issue on behalf of my poor enduser. The is the essence of my question: if someone knows how to set that config

Comment: Ok, I now understand the question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think setting the locale in `dojoConfig` could solve your problem, something like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        isDebug: true,
        locale: 'en-us'
    };
</script>
```

[dojotoolkit - config](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/config.html)

*UPDATE*:

You can use `loadModules` of `esri-loader`, to pass `dojoConfig` options, like this

```
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';

const options = {
  dojoConfig: {
    async: true,
    locale: 'en-us'
  }
};

loadModules(['esri/map'], options)
  .then(([Map]) => {
    // here you create Map
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle any errors
    console.error(err);
  });
```

[esri-loader - without setdefaultoptions](https://github.com/Esri/esri-loader/#without-setdefaultoptions)

Comment: I'm using the arcgis provided react lib esri-loader at (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/react/) I am not clear on where to set the dojo config in the context of this esri provided code snippet. Interesting that the esri site itself (at least on one of my test systems) clearly has this problem too

Comment: Awesome, I'll give that a try and report back!

Comment: You're a genius @cabesuon! That worked. Shame that the arcgis website itself is not following this practice and this answer doesn't seem to be presented (at least not clearly on their getting started docs).

Comment: Glad it help you!